# Publishing SWF file that reads a JSON file

Tags: json, actionscript-2

I've tested my swf in my computer and run ok after have settled the secure sites. But, when I upload the swf and json files to a (free) server, the swf can't communicate with json file despite its permission is 666. The same swf movie, has no problem to read txt and php files, just only with the json one. I've asked to administrator if there is some kind of restriction, now waiting his answer. Could be that a json file represents a potential insecurity for the server? I am not expert in security issues but I've read that in past times, was relatively very easy to attack through json.

Answer (score 1):

sorry. I solved my issue.
It was matter of Flash. Flash can handle numerical strings, say, internally flash understand this "5" + 3, and for Flash, this results is 53 a real number, if you run your swf in your computer, BUT, if you run the swf embed in a web page, this operation produces NAN !!!. I believed as if Flash was not reading my data from JSON file, which they are stored as strings, numerical strings, indeed.

So, I fix simply with this: Number('data from JASON') + 'a real number' + etc

Then, I've explicitly cast as number the (numerical string) datas read from JSON. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the source of the problem but it's worth getting the administrator to check what the JSON MIME type is on the server - it should be application/json.